# Is there a way to embed a user drawn canvas element into a WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf, canvas, datagrid

I've got a `wpf` `datagrid` in my UI.

For one of the columns I'd like to embed a graph, which I draw onto a canvas.
What is the recommended way of embedding a user drawn canvas object into a column of a `datagrid`?

This column will be updated regularly, not static.

I've defined the column like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Market State">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="GraphCtrl"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is it correct to grab the canvas element when the underlying data updates and then draw on it at that time?

Anything I need to take into consideration, ie being on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control that's either based on canvas or contains a canvas part. Expose a dependency property on that control so you can data bind your grid data. If the grid data supports INotifyPropertyChanged your custom control can listen for changes and update accordingly.